# How to use Cloudfront to protect my files

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have a bunch of images on my S3 which is linked with Cloudfront.

Now I have a web server and I only want users to view the image through my website so I can't just give out links to the image. How do I set that?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Content stored in Amazon S3
- Content served via Amazon CloudFront
- Content should be private, but have a way to let specific people view it

This can be accomplished by using **Pre-Signed URLs**. These are special URLs that only work for a limited period of time.

When your application determines that the user is entitled to view an image, it can generate a Pre-Signed URL that grants access for a limited period of time. Simply use this URL in an `<IMG>` tag as you would normally.

See:

- [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)
- [Amazon CloudFront pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Since your content in Amazon S3 will be private (so users cannot bypass CloudFront and access it directly), you will also need to grant CloudFront permission to access the content from S3. See: [Using an Origin Access Identity to Restrict Access to Your Amazon S3 Content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

Another option, instead of creating a pre-signed URL each time, is to use [Signed Cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html). However, this doesn't give fine-grained control for access to individual objects -- it's more for granting access to multiple objects, such as a subscription area.

Comment: There's an additional option of using hotlink protection -- while this isn't a perfect answer, it is now possible using the AWS WAF combined with CloudFront. I agree with your answer, and would recommend using Signed URLs instead - but if adding that feature to the website is tricky, Refer checking in the WAF could be more straightforward.

Comment: About using AWS WAF to control access to CloudFront content, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-awswaf.html